# Conditional CSS Class dependent on age of date

Tags: php, css

I'm trying to create a situation where I have an unordered list (created using Wordpress plugin Advanced Custom Fields) and within it, all list items that have a date older that 30 days have a different css class (so I can style them differently). With this in mind, can anyone show me how to edit the code below so that when `the_sub_field(date)` in the 2nd `div` on each `li` is older than 30 days it will change the `<li class='new'>` to `<li class='old'>`

See code below:

```
        // check for rows
        <?php if( have_rows('item_list_details') ): ?>
            <ul class="admin">
            <?php
            // loop through rows
            while( have_rows('item_list_details') ): the_row() 
                // display each item as a list
                ?>
                   <li class='new'>
                <div class='itemTitle'>
                    <?php the_sub_field('link_name'); ?>
                </div>
                <div class="memberListDate">
                          <?php the_sub_field('date'); ?>
                     </div>
                   </li>   
            <?php endwhile; ?>
            </ul>
        <?php endif; ?>
```

Any help with this would be most appreciated

Comment: What does the code for `the_sub_field(..)` look like?

Comment: It's a date formatted `Ymd`

Comment: Is that what you meant Mr Lister?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace

```
<li class='new'>
```

With

```
<?php
    $date = new DateTime(the_sub_field('date'));
    $now = new DateTime(Date('Y-m-d'));
    $diff = $now->diff($date);

    if ($diff->days > 30):    //Use $diff->days and not $diff->d
?>
    <li class='old'>
<?php else: ?>
    <li class='new'>
<?php endif;?>
```

**Contents of $diff**

```
object(DateInterval)#3 (15) {
  ["y"]=>
  int(0)
  ["m"]=>
  int(0)
  ["d"]=>
  int(18)                        <-------d is relative to a single month
  ["h"]=>
  int(0)
  ["i"]=>
  int(0)
  ["s"]=>
  int(0)
  ["weekday"]=>
  int(0)
  ["weekday_behavior"]=>
  int(0)
  ["first_last_day_of"]=>
  int(0)
  ["invert"]=>
  int(1)
  ["days"]=>
  int(18)                        <--------days is the total days between
  ["special_type"]=>
  int(0)
  ["special_amount"]=>
  int(0)
  ["have_weekday_relative"]=>
  int(0)
  ["have_special_relative"]=>
  int(0)
}
```

**Original Code with var_dump**

`
         "; var_dump(get_sub_field('age')); echo ""; ?>
                        
                        
                                diff($date);

```
                                if ($diff->days > 30):
                            ?>
                                <li class='research'>
                            <?php else: ?>
                                <li class='researchLatest'>
                            <?php endif;?>`
```

Comment: Thanks Vahe . . . most helpful. Can I ask: If I was to make the "30 days" an Advance Custom Fields field which could in fact be various times like 30, 60 or 90 days and named that field 'age' for example, could the if statement part of your code be written like this `if ($diff->d > (the_sub_field('age')):`

Comment: Actually, dynamic is better like you suggest because usually it helps for 2 reasons,  1) for reducing the number of repeated literal values "30" for example, and 2) for eliminating any magic numbers that don't have sufficient self explanation what their intended purpose is.

Comment: Ahh, interesting. Am out of office at the moment but will look into on Wednesday and hopefully all will be fine. Many thanks for your help

Comment: Hi Vahe. Tried it out but all `<li` are rendering as `<li class='new'>` suggesting it's not recognising the "greater than 30 days" state. Also the date is being displayed before each `li`!  Any ideas?

Comment: After <?php there is a typo/bug try new DateTime(the_sub_field('date'));   instead of new DateTime(the_sub_field('date'););   because the semicolon before the final close parenthesis is causing the code to finish for that line preventing assignment portion from being executed therefore the resulting difference is always most likely 0 and causing the new tag from being rendered each time.

Comment: Semi colon before the close parenthesis causes execution of current statement that is the_sub_field('date').  which probably returns or outputs the date.   And halts execution of the line if I am not mistaken. That is what was happening.

Comment: Still having no luck with this! This is the code I've included `<?php
            $date = new DateTime(the_sub_field('date'));
         $now = new DateTime(Date('Y-m-d'));
            $diff = $now->diff($date);
         if ($diff->d > 30):
        ?><li class='research'><?php else: ?><li class='researchLatest'><?php endif;?>`

Comment: However, it still doesn't seem to change the the class name for list items over 30 days old? 

Any ideas?

Comment: you can view the page (in it's current state) here: [link](https://newsite.newcomen.com/my-newcomen/research-sources/)

Comment: Please see updated answer as I mistakenly used $diff->d and not the correct $diff->days

Comment: OK, sorted it! The first line should read
 ` $date = new DateTime(get_sub_field('date'));` 
by changing 'the_sub_field' to 'get_sub_field' you include it in the if statement rather that just printing it. Thanks Vahe

Comment: Thanks Vahe - showing all the array elements for $diff was very helpful

Comment: Now I'm trying implement the dynamic element (as mentioned in my comment on Dec 16th which you agreed would be good. Am changing the line ` if ($diff->days > 30):` to `if ($diff->days > (get_sub_field('item_list_new'))):` where `item_list_new` is a numerical value stored in a Advanced Custom Fields sub field. It's not working though! Any ideas why?

Comment: Would you be able to post the code for the get_sub_field()?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by the code for `get_sub_field` as it's created via ACF (Advanced Custom Fields) Wordpress plugin (are you familiar?). I've included a screenshot of the dashboard where `get_sub_field` is created here [link] (https://newsite.newcomen.com/tempfolder/ScreenShot_ACF_item_list_new.png) (Have shown the dropdown menu for the "return format" and have currently chosen "value")

If you want me to post the full code for this section, I don't know how to post additional code on a StackOverflow post (like you did for `Contents of $diff`) - would love to know how to do that though.

Comment: Insert the following code snippet outside of your loop.  `echo "<pre>"; var_dump(get_sub_field('item_list_new')); echo "</pre>";`  temporarily to see what the contents are of get_sub_field.

Comment: Tried that and the following was displayed `bool(false)`

Comment: instead of 'item_list_new' can you use 'age' in the parameter for get_sub_field, also make sure this snippet for my comment above is placed under have_rows if statement (first line of code in your question)

Comment: Tried to paste complete code below **Contents of $diff** code above but got in a real mess & now don't know how to remove it - please ignore. The code with the Var dump looks like this:

`<?php 
     // check for rows (sub repeater)
     if( have_rows('item_list_details') ): ?>
                     <?php echo "<pre>"; var_dump(get_sub_field('age')); echo "</pre>"; ?>
      <ul class="admin">
      <?php
      // loop through rows (sub repeater)
      while( have_rows('item_list_details') ): the_row() 
       // display each item as a list
       ?>`

Comment: But still get `bool(false)`

Comment: Let's continue in a chat for faster resolution.  https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/info/185696/wordpress-wcf-discussion?tab=access

Comment: Have now got this, which I presume is what we've been looking for:

'array(1) {

  [0]=>

  int(30)

}`

Comment: Sorry can't speak in chat room as need reputation of 20 which i don't have. To resolve I noticed 'age' and 'item_list_details' are both sub fields of an ACF field called 'membership_lists_links (that turns up earlier in the code)' so placed var_dump under have_rows if statement for that field. How does this help solve the issue of using a ACF field to define the number of days?

Comment: You need to capture the value of that method returned value get_sub_field('age') in a variable like $age and use it in the if statement comparing diff to age  remove all snippets we previously added for debug purposes.  If get_sub_field('age') is in fact an array you need to extract the first element of the array by offset [0] like so get_sub_field('age')[0] that will give you the value to store in $age.  I forget if php can allow accessing a 1 element array's value by its name, or if in fact you have to access by subscript notation []

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/185697/discussion-between-vahe-and-phil-legg).